# Consumer disappears from queue after 30-40 mins

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

My app just disappears from the list of consumers in `RabbitMQ Admin` after working just fine for like 30-40 mins. AMQP lib used: [node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp). Here's the connection:

```
const con = amqp.createConnection(options,{defaultExchangeName: 'amq.topic', reconnect: true})
```

The following event handlers are configured too: `connect, ready, close, tag.change, error`

The worst part is that i don't get any errors or close events, app just disconnects and logs nothing...

It just seems that connection is terminated out of being 'idle' for a while...

Has anyone had something similar? How did you deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps someone. To resolve the issue we have to put `heartbeat` field to `options` and specify the interval in seconds the connection has to be checked and refreshed. 
The `heartbeat` is doesn't have any default values, so if it is not explicitly added, amqp won't use it.